# Animate titleView on button click

Tags: ios, animation, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm new to animation in ios and i'm trying to apply an animation on the titleView in the navigationBar but following code keep saying:

```
Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type '(FloatLiteralConvertible, delay: FloatLiteralConvertible, options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: () -> () -> $T4, completion: (($T16) -> ($T16) -> $T15) -> (($T16) -> $T15) -> $T15)'
```

when i remove the

```
self.navigationItem.titleView?.center = CGPointMake(10, 10)
```

there is no error, but how can i apply an animaiton on the titleView/title?

```
@IBAction func animateButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {



    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.navigationItem.titleView?.center = CGPointMake(10, 10)

        }, completion: { finished in
            println("Basket doors opened!")
    })


}
```

Comment: Yes i'm new to animations in IOS and just starting by making some kind of animation? why do i then get the above swift compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 1.0, options:.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
    // Optional chaining may return nil
    _ = self.navigationItem.titleView?.center = CGPointMake(10, 10)
    // return
    }, completion: {
        finished in
        println("Basket doors opened!")
})
```

Comment: Implicit returns from single-expression closures.

Comment: So why is this not animating the titleView?

Comment: Did you set this property to a custom title view?

Comment: No at the moment its just a text title? so what do i need to change in order to animate that?

Comment: You can set it with a `UILabel()` if you just want a text title. `titleView` is `nil` by default.

Comment: [Check the doc](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView)

Comment: I'm confused by this syntax. Why is the "_ = ..." necessary? The animations block doesn't return anything, so why do implicit returns have anything to do with this method?

Comment: Animation block returns `Void`, which is different than `nil`.

Comment: That does' make sense to me. You can get rid of the "_  =" if you change self.navigationItem.titleView?.center to self.navigationItem.titleView!.center. The error messages that you get in Swift are often really screwy.